# what does 0L stands for in c++ accumulate function?

Tags: c++

I came across this line of code shown below, what does 0L stand for?
nums is just a 1d vector. I knew this line of code trying to get the total sum of the nums array.

long r = accumulate(begin(nums), end(nums), 0L) + 1;

Comment: Its a `long` literal zero.

Comment: It means 0 long, without the L it is an integer

Comment: Have you read the specification of this function?

Comment: I did, confused by 0L or OL....lol